# Can Thunderbolt be used to power the host device?

Tags: power, pcie, thunderbolt

Could the [Thunderbolt interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_%28interface%29) be used to provide power to the PCIe **host** device? In this case, this would be a battery-powered mobile device, connecting to a range of peripherals. Thunderbolt here would serve as the extension connector, basically obviating the need for a dedicated docking solution, but the big question is whether the power can flow back to the mobile device without using a separate microUSB plug for that purpose. I'd be extremely grateful for some (preferably sourced) explanation of whether that is possible or not, as my own reading on both Thunderbolt and PCIe failed to give a definitive answer either way.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq#etiquette

Comment: @OlinLathrop  Zeus was in charge of thunderbolts, according to ancient Greek.  Poseidon is in charge of the seas.  Intel is in charge of [Thunderbolt interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_%28interface%29).

Comment: My understanding is that the controllers, and thus the ports, are one way from the host to the peripherals, and the host ports are not designed to accept power, but they are supposed to support just under 10W of power to peripherals at 18V.

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty much impossible to answer this question, since Intel has not put forward a single page of information about the controllers. I've been registered with them since mid-January and it's been dead air since.

Comment: Ouch, that's a shame, it was my step two in the whole thing. But, is there anything in PCIe itself that would answer my question in absence of Thunderbolt? I'm terribly new to the whole thing, so I'm pretty much groping in the dark here.